# Como faço pra aceitar apenas letras no entrada no Ruby?

Tags: string, ruby

Dado uma string, tem que pegar apenas as letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. E na saída mostrar as mesmas. Como posso atingir esse resultado?

Answer (score 1):

```
class String
  def pega_maiusculas
    self.scan /\p{Upper}/
  end
  def pega_minusculas
    self.scan /\p{Lower}/
  end
end

str = "Teste TeStE tEsTe"
maiusculas = str.pega_maiusculas
minusculas = str.pega_minusculas

puts maiusculas
puts "\n"
puts minusculas
```